# How to ask IntelliJ to show all the directories in File → Open? One is missing without clear reason

Tags: intellij-idea

From *IntelliJ*, I would like to open an isolated `Java` source file located in:

`/home/lebihan/dev/apprentissageDev/maths-stats/EstimationPonctuelleEtIntervalleDeConfianceTest.java`

```bash
lebihan@debian:~/dev/apprentissageDev/maths-stats$ pwd
/home/lebihan/dev/apprentissageDev/maths-stats

lebihan@debian:~/dev/apprentissageDev/maths-stats$ ls
EstimationPonctuelleEtIntervalleDeConfianceTest.java
```

When I use *File → Open*, the selector shows me many folders, but not `maths-stats`,
that *GNOME* explorer is able to see: it's a plain normal directory, not hidden, that has the same properties than others.

[image]

How to ask *IntelliJ* to list with *File → Open* all the directories available,
or what should I check that could prevent it from listing one of them,
or what is its rule to filter out some?

Comment: Does clicking the Refresh button in front of the Hide path blue text help? I've tried under ubuntu 22.04, but can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

Epilog:

I drag-dropped the file I was willing to open in the IDE:

- it opened it,
- and at the same time, detected the folder.

When I left IntelliJ, I was warned that some backgrounds process were still in progress:
instead of confirming leaving, I've checked what background tasks were active. But but they were none: the window was empty.